# Please identify the last 3 words in the lyrics of "In a Place Far Far Away" by Paul Robeson

Tags: lyrics

Paul Robeson (1898-1976) once recorded a Chinese song called "In a Place Far Far Away" (["Zai Na Yaoyuan De Difang"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zai_Na_Yaoyuan_De_Difang)).  This is a timeless classic folk song written by Wang Luo-Bin about 80 years ago in northwest China (as inspired by a Kazakh folk song).  The Chinese lyrics and a different translation [are found here](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/%E5%9C%A8%E9%82%A3%E9%81%A5%E8%BF%9C%E7%9A%84%E5%9C%B0%E6%96%B9-distant-place.html).

Could someone please help to identify the last 3 words in Robeson's version of the English lyrics? I think it's "your wasteful glance". But I am not sure. Thanks in advance!

Please find his version [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5iBJuqkbis).

Lyrics:

> In a place far far away,
>   lives a lovely lass.
>   Those who walk past her tent,
>   cast back in **your wasteful glance**[?].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the correct lyric --at least it seems to make more sense in context:

> In a place
>   far far away
>   Lives a lovely lass
>
> Those who walk
>   past her tent
>   cast back **many a wistful glance**

Comment: Thanks a lot. BTW, this is a timeless classic folk song written by Wang Luo-Bin about 80 years ago in northwest China. Some claims that he was inspired by some Kazakh folk song.  Anyway the Chinese version of this 'In a Place Far Far Away' by Wang Luo-Bin has been very popular in China. It still is.